# Applying $toUpper in MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've a JSON arbitraty, I know only the name of the index that contains responses defined as a string, for example:

```
{
   "id_0": "my phrase",
   "id_1": 45.30,
   "id_2": [1.2, 3.5]
}
```

I want apply the transformation phrase that makes my stay in uppercase. For example, the result is:

```
{
   "id_0": "MY PHRASE",
   "id_1": 45.30,
   "id_2": [1.2, 3.5]
}

db.my_collection.aggregate({$toUpper: "id_0"})
```

Don't return a valid answer, has an error.

But pay attention to the fact that it is arbitrary, I do not know how id_n, n being an integer in my JSON exist, only that it is of type Text.

Thank you.

Comment: `db.my_collection.aggregate({$project: { "id_0": { $toUpper: "$id_0" } } })` might work.

Comment: Although, I don't understand what you mean by "it's arbitrary." The aggregation framework may not do what you want, and if possible, I'd suggest performing the uppercase on the client rather than on the database.

Comment: "it's arbitrary" means that for example: {"id_0": 3.4}, a lot of types of JSON exist

Comment: Still would suggest you just fix the case of the letters on your client rather than the database.

Comment: It is not fast but works also to do : db.collection.find().forEach(function(x) { if (typeof x.id_0 === 'string') {print(x.id_0.toUpperCase());} else {print(x.id_0);})

Comment: When you say "I want apply the transformation phrase that makes my stay in uppercase" do you mean that you want to make it stay in uppercase, saved in the database, after the aggregation is over?

If that is what you mean, you should be doing this in the client using something like attish describes above. The aggregation framework is for running more complicated queries that aggregate or reformat data, not for permanently modifying your data.